# Winter bash 2017 counting down page - what's with the fence?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2017

[Winter bash 2017 counting down page is pretty nice](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) ... but I have noticed something rather odd:

[image: fence]

See how every other vertical pole has been pretty much evenly spaced out, every pole except the one near the tree in the red circle?

What happened to the missing pole?

Comment: My guess is that continuing to evenly space it out would have made the tree fill exactly into the gap between poles, making it one unappealing amorphous black mass rather then a clearly delineated fence and tree.

Comment: That is probably where that drunk reindeer went through last year....

Comment: It's an easter egg (wrong season, but oh well). If you click it enough times something cool happens :P

Comment: That's why you do not use tabs.

Comment: That's not even the worst part of this page. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg

Comment: No hand-drawn circle to mark the spot -1

Comment: Have you tried turning the lights on and off? ;)

Comment: @davidp [sure have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs0lE.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, that was Timmy.  He's been getting big lumps of coal the last few years, and this year he decided to fight back.  He's found the perfect vantage point for lobbing snowballs (and coal) at Santa when he lands on the roof, but he needs to be on the other side of that fence.  Problem: Timmy's parents have learned through experience (and complaints from the neighbors) to lock that gate at night so Timmy can't get out and cause trouble.

They didn't lock the workshop in the basement, though, and Timmy found the power saws.  He's betting his parents won't notice his portal project until spring.  He doesn't know that Santa's on to him (seriously, kid, what part of "he knows when you've been naughty" did you miss?), and he'll be sending advance elves to patch that up.  Poor Timmy; Santa's going to need extra elves to carry *this* year's coal.

Comment: Who is Timmy? ... or rather, which Timmy?

Answer (score 19):

In my estate in the West Country, my daughter insists that we have the groundsmen remove a section of the wrought iron park fencing to afford the reindeer safer passage to and from the great house.

Despite my telling her that they fly off, there's no convincing her.

I submit to you therefore that the picture is entirely accurate.

Comment: That is such a posh answer :D. I like it

Comment: What?? Why?? Winterbash is always such fun...